# AdView inside ViewPager or below

Tags: android, android-viewpager, admob, adview

I've taken adView inside a fragment which will be repeated and loaded for each load of the fragment.

Now if a  swipe through 3 pages in ViewPager all the ads are loaded.
Is this allowed / or a good approach ? because by this, i can increase my impression count.

I dont have much experience about AdMob either. (Coz last time i heard they cancelled / discontinued someone's account just because he didn't place his ads as per the norms.)

please suggest correct approach of the following
1. Each View Page Fragment will have its own AdView
2. A common AdView below ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach 1 is better and safe as i have been using approach 1, i currently display ads on top of the page in each fragment and have not run into any trouble as of yet(more than 5 months)so use approach 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend option 2.
Otherwise you will generate a large number of requests with limited CTR.
It is also much less code that you will need to manage, both in your layout and your Activity/Fragment.